# Running maven test on a specific class - [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test

Tags: maven, testing, plugins, testng, surefire

Getting the following issue. When I run `mvn test -Dtest=MyClassTest`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test  
(default-test) on project my-project: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to 
ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

But I have 10 other classes in the same project but on a different path. I ran all of them like this and those all run fine. But mvn test is not identifying just this one. Could there be any problems?

I reviewed the same errors that people got, but was proposed different solutions like upgrade, etc.
But for me, all tests run fine, except this one. So I am kind of in limbo, if I am missing something.

Comment: Can you double check if `MyClassTest` have any method annotated with `@Test` annotation?

Comment: Yes, I did check it. It has it. Its strange. Anything to do with package?

Comment: Hmmm strange. Can you run the test from IDE?

Comment: Thanks much! It seems to be running from eclipse. So the issue from command line!

Answer (score 0):

For those that have the same issue. Its my blunder (maybe). The `@Test` annotated method has no access specifier. I just use void method(). I added `public` and it started working!

Thanks @user2507946. Running from IDE help solve the issue.